# Ubuntu 14.04 Crashes Back to LogIn Window

Tags: 14.04, graphics, login-screen, crash

Just recently crashes started and it simply gets me back to the login window. During the crash, it briefly outlines the message "Starting LightDM Display Manager" and goes to the login window. Once I log in, by default, e.g. Mozilla searches restore and everything continues to operate like nothing happened.

I reviewed similar queries already posted; and it seems like it is the issue with the graphics? The graphic card is ATI Radeon RS690 x1200.

Executed command "Top" and both, "compiz" and "Xorg" showed up. Tried to install all needed drivers through the command:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic"
```

successful.

Any ideas what is causing these crashes?

Comment: Utopic is version 14.10 - Trusty is 14.04 which are you actually using? Check System Settings->Details or `lsb_release -a`

Comment: OP is using 14.04 with the `utopic` graphical stack.